# Understanding bomb lab

Tags: assembly, x86

Hope you can help me to understand how I can find out the six numbers.  Have tried couple set of numbers that I thought was the right ones but guess I´m not understanding it right.

So for the first, this six numbers that I'm looking for, isn´t it numbers that are the outcome or the number that I put in to fit to the code?

Do I have to go through all the code or are there just few lines that I can find out these numbers?  Started to think that I'm over thinking it, that it´s much easier to find those numbers then the ways I´m trying.

```
08048b74 <phase_2>:
 8048b74:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048b75:       83 ec 38                sub    $0x38,%esp
 8048b78:       8d 44 24 18             lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048b7c:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048b80:       8b 44 24 40             mov    0x40(%esp),%eax
 8048b84:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048b87:       e8 28 07 00 00          call   80492b4 <read_six_numbers>
 8048b8c:       83 7c 24 18 00          cmpl   $0x0,0x18(%esp)
 8048b91:       79 22                   jns    8048bb5 <phase_2+0x41>
 8048b93:       e8 dd 06 00 00          call   8049275 <explode_bomb>
 8048b98:       eb 1b                   jmp    8048bb5 <phase_2+0x41>
 8048b9a:       89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax
 8048b9c:       03 44 9c 14             add    0x14(%esp,%ebx,4),%eax
 8048ba0:       39 44 9c 18             cmp    %eax,0x18(%esp,%ebx,4)
 8048ba4:       74 05                   je     8048bab <phase_2+0x37>
 8048ba6:       e8 ca 06 00 00          call   8049275 <explode_bomb>
 8048bab:       83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx
 8048bae:       83 fb 06                cmp    $0x6,%ebx
 8048bb1:       75 e7                   jne    8048b9a <phase_2+0x26>
 8048bb3:       eb 07                   jmp    8048bbc <phase_2+0x48>
 8048bb5:       bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
 8048bba:       eb de                   jmp    8048b9a <phase_2+0x26>
 8048bbc:       83 c4 38                add    $0x38,%esp
 8048bbf:       5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048bc0:       c3                      ret
```

Comment: It's not clear whatsoever what you are asking.

Comment: I´m using gdb in a ssh, I´m trying to find the right 6 numbers so my bomb won´t blow, I´m supposed to find theese 6 numbers out from this assembly code.
I´m sorry if it isn´t clear, but I'm trying to understand it myself and have been stuck for it for 2 days how it works.

Comment: That's not a whole lot of code. Yes, you should try to figure out what it is doing. The important part is at `8048b9a`. Update your question with pseudocode or C code beside the disassembly. Note, the following stages will be harder, so try to learn stuff.

Answer (score 3):

@user3399655, you simply need to read the function disassembly and understand what it does. When you understand it, it will be clear what the six numbers you need to enter are.

1. First, do you know what each instruction in that disassembly does? (PUSH, SUB, LEA, MOV, CALL, CMP...) If not, look up the ones you don't know in [Intel's Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). You want manuals 2A-C. If you don't understand the definition of an instruction, ask a specific question about it here.
2. Do you understand the concept of the call stack? Do you know how space for variables on the stack is allocated, and how they are accessed in assembly? If not, you will not be able to understand this function.
3. Do you know how C control structures like `if...else` and `for(;;)` translate into assembly? Try printing out the disassembly you posted, and draw arrows showing where each conditional/unconditional jump instruction goes. As a hint, it looks like the function has 2 `if` blocks, and a single loop. Can you see which jumps are part of which control structure?
4. OK, another hint. An `if`  block generally translates to a conditional jump, which jumps *over* the contents of the block if the condition is **false**. If the condition is true, it doesn't take the jump, and falls through to the contents of the block. (Does that make sense? Think about it for a minute if you need to.) Loops translate to conditional jumps which jump *backwards* if the condition for ending the loop is not met.
5. The loop has a single index variable. Can you see which register the index variable is kept in? Can you tell if it steps up or down? And how far does it step before the loop terminates?
6. Can you tell where in `phase_2`'s stack frame the 6 numbers will be kept? How many bytes are used for each one? You could try to read the code for `read_six_numbers` if you need to. Or just run the code in a debugger, and look at the stack.

Comment: Thank you for giving you time to answer me with some information :)

Comment: @user3399655, in response to what you said, the loop variable is not held in EAX. It's a register which is initialized when the loop starts, is ADDed to once on each iteration, and which is used for a CMP/JNE which jumps to the beginning of the loop when the condition for termination is not met. About where the numbers are kept on the stack, try entering "1 2 3 4 5 6", `x/40w $esp` in `gdb` (after `read_six_numbers` returns), and look for those numbers. See what is the offset (in bytes) from `*$esp` where they are stored.

Comment: This is important, because the 6 numbers are stored as an array on the stack, and the code uses addresses relative to `$esp` to access them. If you know where they are relative to `$esp`, you may be able to figure out which elements of the array are accessed on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving you time to answer me Alex D with some information :)  It was to long to comment to your answer.

1. I´m understanding most of those instruction does.  I know now that cmp is the big part that I have to watch for.
2. I think I know some about call stack.
3. I should know how if else and for in C are translated into assembly.
4. I´ve been watching in gdb using stepping how it goes through the loops (jumps) and have got to 5 jumps now and stop at the 6th one so I think I´m getting closer.
5. Think it´s EAX if I´m watching gdb, it´s getting higher with stepping.
6. Don´t think I could tell that.

Thank you again for giving time to comment back, think it will be much easier when the lights turn on in my head :)