# Binary Bomb phase 2

Tags: unix, assembly

I'm extremely confused if this assembly code will print 1,2,6,24,120,720 as the six numbers or not. I have tried to go through this multiple times in GDB and I see eax values fluctuating from 1,2,3 and 6 and then it just doesn't loop through more than twice for some reason. I'm really stuck on this, any help would be appreciated. This is not related to the other binary bomb phase 2 post as this one is different.

```
0x000000000040129f <+0>:        push   %rbp
0x00000000004012a0 <+1>:        push   %rbx
0x00000000004012a1 <+2>:        sub    $0x28,%rsp
0x00000000004012a5 <+6>:        mov    %rsp,%rsi
0x00000000004012a8 <+9>:        callq  0x40185a <read_six_numbers>
0x00000000004012ad <+14>:       cmpl   $0x1,(%rsp)
0x00000000004012b1 <+18>:       je     0x4012be <phase_2+31>
0x00000000004012b3 <+20>:       mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004012b8 <+25>:       callq  *0x2034e2(%rip)        # <explode>
0x00000000004012be <+31>:       mov    %rsp,%rbx
0x00000000004012c1 <+34>:       mov    $0x1,%ebp
0x00000000004012c6 <+39>:       mov    (%rbx),%eax
0x00000000004012c8 <+41>:       lea    (%rax,%rax,2),%eax
0x00000000004012cb <+44>:       mov    %eax,%edx
0x00000000004012cd <+46>:       xor    0x4(%rbx),%edx
0x00000000004012d0 <+49>:       mov    %ebp,%ecx
0x00000000004012d2 <+51>:       sar    %cl,%eax
0x00000000004012d4 <+53>:       cmp    %eax,%edx
0x00000000004012d6 <+55>:       je     0x4012e3 <phase_2+68>
0x00000000004012d8 <+57>:       mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004012dd <+62>:       callq  *0x2034bd(%rip)       <explode>
0x00000000004012e3 <+68>:       add    $0x1,%ebp
0x00000000004012e6 <+71>:       add    $0x4,%rbx
0x00000000004012ea <+75>:       cmp    $0x6,%ebp
0x00000000004012ed <+78>:       jne    0x4012c6 <phase_2+39>
0x00000000004012ef <+80>:       add    $0x28,%rsp
0x00000000004012f3 <+84>:       pop    %rbx
0x00000000004012f4 <+85>:       pop    %rbp
0x00000000004012f5 <+86>:       retq
```

This is what I'm getting in my second iteration for the registers. Now there won't be another iteration since rax and rdx are not equal so that last jump will not be executed. This is confusing me because I'm thinking it should be able to loop back till 6 numbers appear.

```
rax            0x1  1
rbx            0x7fffffffe1f4   140737488347636
rcx            0x2  2
rdx            0x5  5
rsi            0x402e7d 4206205
rdi            0x7fffffffdb21   140737488345889
rbp            0x2  0x2
rsp            0x7fffffffe1f0   0x7fffffffe1f0
r8             0x3e9258ee40 268743274048
r9             0x100    256
r10            0xb  11
r11            0xb  11
r12            0x400e30 4197936
r13            0x7fffffffe320   140737488347936
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x4012d8 0x4012d8 <phase_2+57>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
```

Comment: What does `read_six_numbers` return? How does that function work? Is it one that you already know something about? The instruction immediately after that is comparing the value at the top of the stack to 1. If that value is *not* one, then it jumps to `+31`. You should be able to trace the code line-by-line from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding bomb lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435018/understanding-bomb-lab)

Comment: @Bo persson it is not the same one. Cody what do you mean by what read_six_numbers returns? It just asks for six numbers and the first one has to be 1 and then if it is then it jumps to 31. The issue is when I'm trying to trace it during the second iteration it won't meet that last jump's condition and will eventually hit the explode in gdb.

Comment: You can use the first check to figure out the second number, then restart and do the same for the 3rd, and so on. If you can't see it from the code, that is :)

Comment: @Jester, us? I'm thinking it is 1,2,6 but not sure about the next few. I've tried running it in gdb multiple times but it won't get to the iteration for the 3rd number.

Comment: it is not 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have determined that:

- first number is 1
- there is a loop iterating through the numbers
- there is a condition that must be true

Let's look at the loop. It should be obvious that `ebp` is the counter and `rbx` is a pointer going through the numbers.

Now, the condition. How do the two operands get set? For `eax` we can see it's loaded from `(%rbx)` which is the current number, then some operations are performed on it. We don't really care what, since the first number is known, thus we can not change the result.

The other operand is `edx`. That is also calculated from the current number somehow, but is also `xor`-ed with the next number (the `xor 0x4(%rbx),%edx` line).

Armed with all this information, let's enter `1 0 0 0 0 0` as first guess. Note that `xor` with `0` leaves the number unchanged. Let the program run until the comparison and check what's in `eax` and `edx`. It will be `1` and `3`, which are not equal unfortunately. As discussed above, we can not change `eax` but we can change `edx` by using the xor with the next number. Due to how `xor` works, `eax ^ edx` will be our next number. You can have gdb print it as `p $eax ^ $edx`. Now, restart the program and enter this number in place of the first zero placeholder. Let the loop run one more iteration and repeat the process to get the rest of the numbers.